# Can I use conditions directly to assign a variable in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

```
bool bVal;
int a = 5;
int b = 2;

bVal = (bool)a>b;
```

Is the statement `bVal =a>b;` acceptable. Of course, this is working fine for me.

But I see people using something like this:

```
#define CHECK_bIsTrue(value)  ((value) ? TRUE : FALSE)
```

Why do we have use ternary operator if it are just boolean values?

Comment: `bVal = (bool)a>b;` is wrong (and will give the wrong result here), but `bVal = a>b;` is correct.

Comment: I think the `#define` macro "normalizes" true values (anything != 0) to TRUE. Seems redundant if `value` is already boolean.

Comment: @vigneswaran j Sometimes it is necessary that an expression returns exactly either 1 or 0. Consider for example bitwise AND operator x & 8. If the corresponding bit is indeed set then the expression does not return 1.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `!!(<some expression>)` (eg `!!(x & 8)`) to fold the result to 0 or 1. Though it's somewhat more cryptic.

Comment: `bVal = (bool)a>b;` means `bVal = ((bool)a)>b;` so it won't return the correct result.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow to normalize values to 1 or 0 `!!` is  better. For example `#define CHECK_bIsTrue(value)  (!!(value))`

Comment: `a < b` doesn't need any normalization, its result is always `0` or `1`. For the macro don't use self invented names for Boolean values. Either use `0` or `1` or use the names `true` and `false` that `stdbool.h` provide.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt It is less readabele and sometimes confuses readers of the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, what is less readable? Are you trying to say that `TRUE` is more readable than `true`?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt I want to say that TRUE or true is more readable then !!.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `bVal = a>b;` is perfectly correct.

The use of the ternary for such a simple assignment is overkill, and the use of a macro is unjustified.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `a > b` is guaranteed to produce either non-zero or zero which is sufficient for C operators as `if`, `while` etc. But sometimes people for whatever reason want to get definitely either `1` (or `TRUE`) or `0` (or `FALSE`) which is the why they use macros.

Comment: `true` and `false` from stdbool.h are preferred. Don't use `TRUE` and `FALSE`, it suggests that your code is obsolete pre-C99 style.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need exactly 1 or 0 for some expression.

Consider an example.

Let's assume that you decided to write some general function applied to integer arrays that will count something according to the given condition.

The function can look the following way

```
int count( int a[], size_t n, int predicate( int x ) )
{
    int cnt = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cnt += predicate( a[i] );

    return cnt;
}
```

As you see the function is implemented such a way that it just adds the result of the predicate to variable `cnt`.

```
cnt += predicate( a[i] );
```

However it is not necessary that predicate returns exactly 1 or 0.

For example some standard C functions that could be used like predicates  usually return some non-zero value to specify that the condition is true. For example according to the description of such functions from `<ctype.h>` like `isdigit`, `isalpha` and so on there is written in the C Standard (7.4.1 Character classification functions)

> 1 The functions in this subclause return **nonzero** (true) if and
>   only if the value of the argument c conforms to that in the
>   description of the function. For example let's assume that there

And there are many such functions in the C Standard (consider for example one more function `strcmp`).

Thus returning to the example of the function `count` if it will be used as it is written the result of its execution can be incorrect

For example let's assme that there exists already function that returns a **non-zero** value if the second bit of a number is set

```
int is_2nd_bit_set( int x ) { return x & 2; }
```

In this case if you run this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count( int a[], size_t n, int predicate( int x ) )
{
    int cnt = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cnt += predicate( a[i] );

    return cnt;
}

int is_2nd_bit_set( int x ) { return x & 2; }

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "there are %d numbers that have 2nd bit set\n", count( a, N, is_2nd_bit_set ) );
}
```

you get wrong result

```
there are 10 numbers that have 2nd bit set
```

To get the correct result you have to rewrite the corresponding statement in the function the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cnt += ( predicate( a[i] ) ? 1 : 0 );
```

Some programmers used the negation operator ! applied two times to an expression to get exactly 1 or 0. For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cnt += !!predicate( a[i] );
```

But such a code can confuse readers.

Now when type `_Bool` was introduced in the C Standard the statement can be written simpler

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cnt += ( _Bool )predicate( a[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

For historical reasons, all C operands that yield a boolean result, such as the `>` operator, actually returns type `int` with value 1 or 0. This makes C odd, because even though there is nowadays a boolean type in the language, all logical and boolean operations still work on an `int` type.

`(bool)a>b` is wrong because it is pointless: it converts the `a` operand to `bool` before the operation. But the operation itself promotes both operands to `int`, so the only thing the cast could have achieved was a (unlikely and irrelevant) loss of value.

If you are overly picky about type correctness, you could explicitly cast the result type to bool, by using `bVal = (bool)(a>b);` which essentially is the very same thing as `bVal = a>b;`. Either is fine.

The macro you posted is not only pointless, it is bad practice. One should not attempt to invent a personal version of the C language with icky function-like macros. Also, use the pre-defined macros `true` and `false`, rather than the non-standard `TRUE` and `FALSE`.